# Jenkins: read an existing job's plugin config via Groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

We are in the early phases of using Jenkins DSL.  One challenge we have come across is being able to read in an existing jobs plugin settings so that we retain it before running the DSL.  This allows us the ability to give the Jenkins users the option to keep some of their settings.  We have successfully retained the schedule settings for our jobs but the newest challenge is being able to retain a plugin setting.  Specifically a setting in the "ExtendedEmailPublisher" plugin.  We would like to retain the value:

[image]

In the config.xml file for this job in the ExtendedEmailPublisher tags we see the following:

```
<publishers>
    <hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher>
        <recipientList>Our_Team@Our_Team.com</recipientList>
        <configuredTriggers>
            <hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.trigger.FailureTrigger>
                <email>
                    <recipientList/>
                    <subject>$PROJECT_DEFAULT_SUBJECT</subject>
                    <body>$PROJECT_DEFAULT_CONTENT</body>
                    <recipientProviders>
                        <hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.recipients.ListRecipientProvider/>
                    </recipientProviders>
                    <attachmentsPattern/>
                    <attachBuildLog>false</attachBuildLog>
                    <compressBuildLog>false</compressBuildLog>
                    <replyTo>$PROJECT_DEFAULT_REPLYTO</replyTo>
                    <contentType>project</contentType>
                </email>
            </hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.trigger.FailureTrigger>
        </configuredTriggers>
        <contentType>default</contentType>
        <defaultSubject>$DEFAULT_SUBJECT</defaultSubject>
        <defaultContent>$DEFAULT_CONTENT</defaultContent>
        <attachmentsPattern/>
        <presendScript>$DEFAULT_PRESEND_SCRIPT</presendScript>
        <classpath/>
        <attachBuildLog>false</attachBuildLog>
        <compressBuildLog>false</compressBuildLog>
        <replyTo>$DEFAULT_REPLYTO</replyTo>
        <saveOutput>false</saveOutput>
        <disabled>false</disabled>
    </hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher>
</publishers>
```

The value we would like to extract/preserve from this XML is:

```
<disabled>false</disabled>
```

We have tried getting the existing values using groovy but cant seem to find the right code.  Our first idea was to try to read the value from the config.xml using the XmlSlurper. We ran this from the Jenkins Script Console:

```
def projectXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText("curl http://Server_Name:8100/job/Job_Name/api/xml".execute().text);
*we use 8100 for our Jenkins port
```

Unfortunately while this does return some config info it does not return plugin info.

Then, we also tried running the following to read/replace the existing settings:

```
def oldJob = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("Job_Name")
def isDisabled = false // Default Value

for(publisher in oldJob.publishersList) {
  if (publisher instanceof hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher) {
    isDisabled = publisher.disabled
  }
}
```

And while this works if executed from the Jenkins Script Console, when we try to use it in a DSL Job we get the message:

```
Processing provided DSL script
ERROR: startup failed:
script: 25: unable to resolve class 
hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher 
 @ line 25, column 37.
   if (publisher instanceof hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher) 
{
1 error

Finished: FAILURE
```

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

Using url @aflat's URL suggestion for getting the raw XML config info, I was able to use the XML Slurper and then use the `getProperty` method to assign the property I wanted to a variable.

```
def projectXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText("curl http://Server_Name:8100/job/Job_Name/config.xml".execute().text);
def emailDisabled = projectXml.publishers."hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher".getProperty("disabled");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to parse the config.xml, use

```
def projectXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText("curl http://Server_Name:8100/job/Job_Name/config.xml");
```

That should return your raw config.xml data

Comment: tried your command and got an error.  The thing is, if you look at my original post, I have already tried using XmlSlurper

    `def projectXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText("curl http://Server_Name:8100/job/Job_Name/api/xml".execute().text);`

While this returns some info from the config.xml, it does not return the info I am looking for which is the section that pertains to the plugin settings

Comment: Job_name/api/xml and Job_Name/config.xml return 2 very different things. api/xml returns the api endpoints of the Job_name page, config.xml is the actual configuration xml stored on your jenkins server.

Comment: thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction.  You were 100% right.  From the Jenkins Script Console I ran:

    `def projectXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText("curl http://Server_Name:8100/job/Job_Name/config.xml".execute().text);`

I updated my post above with your tip and how i used it to get my problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Under "Manage Jenkins->Configure Global Security" did you try disabling "Enable script security for Job DSL scripts"?